# Context menu file hash for local user

Tags: batch-file, registry, md5, sha1, sha256

It is very nice tools for getting hashes of files (md5, sha1, sha256)
https://github.com/anseki/hashfile-contextmenu/

But local user has no access to HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT

1) What is equivalents string key into HKEY_CURRENT_USER, is it possibly?

2) Can anyone rewrite the command for simple BAT file?

Answer (score 0):

There's no need for a batch file, in the `.reg` files just replace all instances of:

```bat
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT
```

With

```bat
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes
```

*Remember too that `.reg` files usually need to be `Run as administrator`*

If you really do need to use a batch file then the following should be roughly equivalent to using `hashfile-contextmenu-add.reg`

```bat
@Echo Off
Rem MD5
Reg Add "HKCU\Software\Classes\*\shell\hashfileMD5" /VE /D "Copy MD&5" /F>Nul
Reg Add "HKCU\Software\Classes\*\shell\hashfileMD5\command" /VE /D "Cmd /Q /V:ON /C \"For /F \"Delims=\" %%%%A In ('CertUtil -hashfile \"%%L\" MD5^^^|FindStr/V \":\"') Do Set \"hash=%%%%A\"^&Set/P \"=!hash: =!\"^<Nul^|Clip\"" /F>Nul
Rem SHA1
Reg Add "HKCU\Software\Classes\*\shell\hashfileSHA1" /VE /D "Copy SHA&1" /F>Nul
Reg Add "HKCU\Software\Classes\*\shell\hashfileSHA1\command" /VE /D "Cmd /Q /V:ON /C \"For /F \"Delims=\" %%%%A In ('CertUtil -hashfile \"%%L\" SHA1^^^|FindStr/V \":\"') Do Set \"hash=%%%%A\"^&Set/P \"=!hash: =!\"^<Nul^|Clip\"" /F>Nul
Rem SHA256
Reg Add "HKCU\Software\Classes\*\shell\hashfileSHA256" /VE /D "Copy SHA&256" /F>Nul
Reg Add "HKCU\Software\Classes\*\shell\hashfileSHA256\command" /VE /D "Cmd /Q /V:ON /C \"For /F \"Delims=\" %%%%A In ('CertUtil -hashfile \"%%L\" SHA256^^^|FindStr/V \":\"') Do Set \"hash=%%%%A\"^&Set/P \"=!hash: =!\"^<Nul^|Clip\"" /F>Nul
```

---

**Edit**

As a result of your comments, which I do not understand at all.

Files of type `.reg` are usually required to be run as administrator, the specific location within the registry is not considered.

Here are three different scripts, each using the commands which could have been retrieved from your own registry, *after having made the replacements I suggested above and merging either the `.reg` files or my above 'batch' script*:

`Get-MD5.cmd`

```bat
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
For /F "Delims=" %%A In ('CertUtil -hashfile "%~1" MD5^|FindStr/V ":"') Do Set "hash=%%A"&Set/P "=!hash: =!"<Nul|Clip
```

`Get-SHA1.cmd`

```bat
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
For /F "Delims=" %%A In ('CertUtil -hashfile "%~1" SHA1^|FindStr/V ":"') Do Set "hash=%%A"&Set/P "=!hash: =!"<Nul|Clip
```

`Get-SHA256.cmd`

```bat
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
For /F "Delims=" %%A In ('CertUtil -hashfile "%~1" SHA256^|FindStr/V ":"') Do Set "hash=%%A"&Set/P "=!hash: =!"<Nul|Clip
```

*Please note I used the extension `.cmd` for my 'batch' scripts but you can change it to `.bat` if you feel more comfortable living in the last century*.

Comment: > usually need to be Run as administrator

Comment: why? the HCU is accessed for user. NMnd, I try to create it by hand-self,

Comment: Thank you for advise! But I wanted batch-file from "command", to got the hash into clipboard like this C:>sha256.bat  filename

Comment: I try to read the command string, but not understood some expressions

Comment: If you want the actual commands, then it should have been a simple matter of merging the registry or batch file then navigating to the registry keys and copying them directly from there into a batch file! I have updated the answer providing the code for you under **Edit**.